# Using namespace and use in php/laravel?

Tags: php

I have two files in the same directory `Graph`:

```
IModel.php

DataModel.php
```

For these files in the top I set namespace as: `namespace App\Library\Graph;`

When I try to use `IModel.php` in `DataModel.php` I do:

```
namespace App\Library\Graph;

use IModel;
```

I get response: `Interface 'IModel' not found`

Comment: Or I need specify full path like: `App\Library\Graph\IModel;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the php file and then you will be able to call the class.

```
require('App\Library\Graph\IModel.php');

$myClass = new IModel();
```

You can also use an autoloader.. Then include the autoloader and all your classes that are mapped through the autoloader will be able to be called.

Here is a link to read about autoloading using composer.

https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer